# Resteasy throwing error RESTEASY003215 for type javax.ws.rs.core.Form

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a Java app that uses Resteasy 4. I recently added a 3rd party library that requires Jersey. When that 3rd party library makes a call to `javax.ws.rs.client.SyncInvoker#post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<?>)`, the post method throws

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: 
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form
```

I suspect that this is happening because the 3rd party library is somehow calling the Resteasy implementation of this method instead of the Jersey implementation. And, as far as I understand, the Resteasy implementation must not know how to serialize `javax.ws.rs.core.Form` or something, right? So what do I do? Is there any way to get these two jars to work alongside each other? Can I somehow register `javax.ws.rs.core.Form` with the Resteasy implemenation of SyncInvoker? Or is this simply not possible?

Edit:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167002/is-a-project-with-jersey-2-x-and-resteasy-dependencies-possible) is similar to mine but is that answer still correct in 2021?

Edit: stack trace

```
 org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invokePropagateNotFound$6(SynchronousDispatcher.java:308)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:287)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:253)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:67)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
  at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
  at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
  at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.myapp.servlet.XslfFilter.doFilter(XslfFilter.java:41)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.myapp.servlet.diagnostic.LogMemoryFilter.doFilter(LogMemoryFilter.java:25)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.myapp.servlet.cleanliness.ObjectifyCacheClearFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyCacheClearFilter.java:27)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.myapp.servlet.diagnostic.LogMemoryFilter.doFilter(LogMemoryFilter.java:25)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.myapp.servlet.diagnostic.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:19)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
  at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:28)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:567)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:599)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:297)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:492)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:67)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:226)
  at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.requestJWTUserToken(ApiClient.java:850)
  at com.myapp.docusign.OAuth2TokenAcquirer.acquireToken(OAuth2TokenAcquirer.java:43)
  at com.myapp.docusign.OAuth2TokenAcquirer.getAccessToken(OAuth2TokenAcquirer.java:31)
  at com.myapp.docusign.ApiClientFactory.create(ApiClientFactory.java:32)
  at com.myapp.docusign.EnvelopeUploader.create(EnvelopeUploader.java:22)
  at com.myapp.docusign.DocusignService.create(DocusignService.java:16)
  at com.myapp.service.doFoo(FooService.java:65)
  at com.myapp.doBar(BarService.java:1271)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:646)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:510)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:460)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:462)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:420)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:394)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
  ... 95 more
 Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:50)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:302)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.syncProceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:240)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:224)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:444)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:601)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.buildEntity(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:560)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.loadHttpMethod(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:465)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:275)
  ... 121 more
```

Comment: Yes, if you have both clients on the classpath and your code just uses the standard JAX-RS client code, it will default to always using the RestEasy one. Always. It's coded that way. You would need to specifically use JerseyClientBuilder to build the JerseyClient instead of the Standard JAX-RS ClientBuilder

Comment: I don't see any reason why the RestEasy client would not work for Form and application/x-www-form-urlecoded though. This is a standard type and should work.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha So, based on your first comment, you're saying that these two libraries can work together, contrary to what that linked question said 6 years ago?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Also, while trying to research this myself, I've seen several references to a jar called `resteasy-jackson-provider`, that allegedly might be related to my problem. Are you familiar with this jar? if not I'll keep researching.

Comment: Yes, they can definitely work together. That jar is for JSON support for RestEasy. I don't think it has anything to do with the problem as your problem is for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Okay, thanks for the help!

Comment: If you posted the entire stack trace, that might help

Comment: I've added what my logs gave me, but I suspect what my logs gave me might be missing a key part; I'm not sure.

Comment: I've the issue isn't obvious to you, don't worry about it; I'll probably just not use this 3rd party library that's causing issues.